# PHP: Inserting using sqlsrv pdo using triggers

Tags: php, sql-server, triggers, pdo, unique

I'm using sqlsrv pdo driver (used both 5.2 and 5.3 versions) and I'm seeing what I believe is unintended behavior.  Hopefully I'm doing something wrong.

I've created 2 tables in sql express 2008.  One (**Locations**) is a table of primary keys shared with other tables.  The other table (**Rooms**) has 2 (or more) columns...a key column linked as a foreign key to the first table and one (or more) data columns.  So it looks like:

**Locations**

> LocationID int
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5

**Rooms**

> LocationID int, Roomname varchar(50)
>   2, 'living'
>   4, 'dining'

2,4 both link back to the Locations table.

Then I create a unique constraint on the Roomname column:

```
ALTER TABLE Rooms ADD CONSTRAINT UniqueRoom UNIQUE (Roomname)
```

Next, I created an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on the **Rooms** table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Rooms_INSERT] 
on [dbo].Rooms 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
as 
BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO dbo.Locations DEFAULT VALUES 
 INSERT INTO dbo.Rooms select @@IDENTITY, Roomname from inserted    
END
```

Now I can insert data into the rooms table by:

```
INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES (null, 'roomname')
```

I use the sqlsrv PDO object to insert data through PHP:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=db", "", "");

$sql=("insert into Rooms values (null,?)");
$dbobj = $db->prepare($sql);
if($dbobj->execute(array("dining")))
    print "<p>insert successful</p>";
else
    print "<p>insert unsuccessful</p>";
```

Starting with the table listing above, I get the following results:

- Modify insert statement to "insert into Rooms values (?)" - fails as expected because it expects two args, "insert unsuccessful."
- Revert insert statement to normal, attempt to insert array("bedroom") - successful as expected, "insert successful."
- Re-attempt insert of array("bedroom") - db insert fails, no entries are made in either table, but attempt is reported successful "insert successful."

Why is the 3rd attempt reported as successful when there were no lasting entries made to the database? Or, more specifically, how can I modify either my PHP or my SQL to properly detect when an insert like this fails due to a violation of a unique constraint?

Comment: After a suggestion, I tested without the unique constraint and instead violated the Foreign Key constraint by modifying the trigger to only attempt an insert of a non-existing Locations value into the Rooms table.  The result is the same.  It looks like PHP is calling the fired trigger a success, even if the trigger itself fails.

Comment: Did you find the solution?